# What do you call an interfix that has semantic meaning?

Tags: linguistics, phonology

At university I was introduced to various affixes; prefix, suffix, interfix.

The latter, I was told, could be created by putting an adjective in the middle of a word, thus interrupting it; *abso-bloody-lutely* or *done-diddely-one* (as used by The Simpsons' character Ned Flanders). It is highly likely this kind of 'interruption' is mostly used in spoken language.

However, according to Wikipedia, Glottopedia, and other sites, an interfix has no intrinsic meaning and is phonological, used to link two morphemes; *speed-o-meter*, for instance.

What I would like to know is what to call an "interfix" that may have meaning, and/or is used as a form of exaggeration. Is it still considered an interfix?

Comment: I thought this was called an *infix*. Are these different words for the same thing, or different words for similar things?

Comment: I thought infixes did not have meaning either, like saying 'shizz' instead of 'shit' (pardon the language) in rap.

Comment: Wikipedia says [English has almost no true infixes (as opposed to ***tmesis***), and those it does have are marginal.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix) As you can see there, there are a few "true" infixes in chemistry terminology, but mostly they're ridiculously non-standard (for example ***hizouse*** for *house* and ***shiznit*** for *shit*). Note that *abso-bloody-lutely*, etc. is tmesis. I never heard of ***interfix***, and I doubt it has much currency (or even a "fixed" meaning).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some disagree about the terminology, as should be expected, but semantic value is *the* distinction between an 'interfix' and an 'infix' in English.

An 'interfix' is

> (linguistics) An empty morph inserted between two morphemes in the process of word formation, such as English -o-, -i-.

[interfix. (n.d.). Retrieved December 16th, 2015, from http://www.yourdictionary.com/interfix.]

For 'interfixes' the inserted morph has only a phonological value. Such morphs are represented in *speedometer* and *humaniform*.

An 'infix', also called an 'integrated adjective', has semantic value as denoted by the alternative term. 'Integrated adjectives' modify the semantics of the associated nouns, usually but not always by intensifying them:

> An infix is a word element (a type of affix) that can be inserted within the base form of a word (rather than at its beginning or end) to create a new word or intensify meaning. Also called an integrated adjective.

(From ["infix (words and grammar): Glossary of Grammatical and Rhetorical Terms"](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/infixterm.htm) at *About education*.)

Examples of infixes include *anyoldhow*, *absobloodylutely*.

As quoted at the latter source, R.L. Trask in *The Penguin Dictionary of English Grammar* (2000) points out that the closest thing to a 'true' infix in English is the pluralizing -s in compounds:

> English has no true infixes, but the plural suffix -s behaves something like an infix in unusual plurals like *passers-by* and *mothers-in-law*.

Trask's justification for excluding 'integrated adjectives' from the class of "true infixes", as well as his justification for excluding the plurals of compounds, are not readily ascertained from online sources.

The central disagreement about the terminology stems, again as might be expected, from a technical point. Hairs are split about the terms 'interfix', 'infix' and 'circumfix':

> Technically, it also possible to have an *infix* (added in the middle of a stem), an *interfix* (in between two stems) and a *circumfix* (added on either side of a stem), but these are extremely rare in English.

(From [*The History of English*](http://thehistoryofenglish.com/glossary.html), L. Mastin, 2011. Emphasis mine.)

By this definition, 'infix' is exampled by *absobloodylutely*, 'interfix' is exampled by *anyoldhow*, and 'circumfix' is exampled by *unconsciousness*.

The definition proposed suggests that 'integrated adjective' is not an sufficient alternative term for 'infix', and defines  'interfix' in contrast to 'infix' by morphological features rather than the presence or absence of semantic value.

Comment: So we can determine that an interfix is phonological  at best after all, with no semantic value. Then, perhaps the term I look for is integrated adjective? Or, as mentioned by @FumbleFingers, can it be considered a tmesis?

Comment: Fascinating. After some further poking around the internet I found it may be called an 'expletive infix', which is used colloquially.

Comment: @GeoKoer, agreed, fas-odd-cinating. The infix need not be an expletive, of course, but when it is, "expletive infix" works well.

Comment: JEL, you should add examples of each as you go along.

Answer (score 1):

Old post but could be helpful for others searching for some clarity with these two similar affix categories.

I believe JEL’s answer above is correct except that there’s a fundamental difference that separates affixes between infixation, interfixation and circumfixation.

The best way to identify an infix is that the stem word is split in two.  “Abso-bloody-lutely” falls under this category. “Abso” and “Lutely” carry no meaning when split apart.

An interfix is different because it requires TWO stem words on each side of this affix placed in the center.
So “Any-old-how” clearly includes “Any” and “How” are independent morphemes which can stand alone and still have meaning to them or be used in a sentence unbound.

Circumfix are very easy to identify because the stem will remain in the middle of the new word. Instead the affix will be attached at the front and end of the word. The hard part is differentiating a circumfix from a word vs. a word with both a prefix and suffix included. The only difference is that a circumfix will always be used together, in contrast to prefixes and suffixes being able to attach independently without the other present. Luckily, it’s mostly agreed upon that circumfixation is not very common in the English language but there are discussions and studies recently that would argue they are much more abundant that previously thought but it really blurs the lines between circumfixes and the inclusion of both prefix and suffix use.