# Are there any formal infixes?

Tags: suffixes, prefixes

Infixes appear in words such as 'absolutely' to form 'abso-bloody-lutely', or as 'educate' to 'edu-ma-cate' in the Simpsons. I was wondering if there were any formal infixes.

The only ones I could come across were accepted by Merriam Webster and were 'cupsful' and 'handsful' (as opposed to the more common 'cupfuls' and 'handfuls'), and they don't seem overly correct, either.

The question this has been marked as a duplicate of is similar, though not the same, in the sense that prefixes 'un' and 'de' are not the same. My question was more so in regard to the words 'cupsful' and 'handsful' and whether or not they are acceptable alternatives to their common counterparts, though I didn't specify that very clearly. Thank you to Mari-Lou A and JEL for assisting me in finding the answer to the former question.

Comment: Yes, they have them in Tagalog and a handful of other languages.

Comment: Related: [What do you call an interfix that has semantic meaning?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294394/what-do-you-call-an-interfix-that-has-semantic-meaning). From the answer: "the closest thing to a 'true' infix in English is the pluralizing -s in compounds".

Comment: It's a lovely question but unfortunately it's been asked before. OK, the wording is not identical but the substance is the same. Any new answers should be posted on the older question, it is best if they are grouped together rather than spread out between three or four identical questions.

Comment: I attempted to find a similar question to this and was surprised at the lack of - I believed the difference between this question and that was enough to warrant the creation of another question. However, while the question was considerably different from a severely pedantic point of view, the answer was provided in the third section of the answer, which I must have overlooked. Thank you for bringing it back to my attention!